# Problem with aligning using compactlist in tabularx

Tags: tables, indentation, tabularx

I've created a table with the tabularx package. Within the cells I use compactitem to create a list. First I had a problem with the leftmargin. To solve this I've used `\setlength{\leftmargini}{0pt}`. But now I've got the problem, that when there's a line break, the sentence starts right below the bullet point without no indentation. Can anybody help me with this problem? 
There are probably other things that could have been done better, but that's my first experience with TeX ever :)

```
\makeatletter
\def\MPT{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}l|X|X|X|}   %vier Spalten
\hline
\rowcolor[gray]{0.75}
\textbf{} & \textbf{Herkömmlicher Festpreis} & \textbf{Time \& Material} & \textbf{Agiler Festpreis} \\ \hline\hline
\centering\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{sideways}\parbox{40mm}{Kunde}\end{sideways}}
&
-
&
--
&
++
\\
\cline{2-4}
&
\setlength{\leftmargini}{0pt}
\begin{compactitem}
\setlength{\itemsep}{-1\parsep}
\MPT
\item Budgetsicherheit ist nicht gegeben, der Preis basiert nur auf Schätzwert um wieviel der ursprüngliche Festpreis überschritten wird
\item Risiko der Budgetsicherheit ist zwar geteilt, aber meist stärker auf Kundenseite
\vspace{-0.5cm}
\end{compactitem}
&
\setlength{\leftmargini}{0pt}
\begin{compactitem}
\setlength{\itemsep}{-1\parsep}
\MPT
\item Kunde kann die Aufwände im Detail im Budgetrahmen steuern
\item Hoher Kontrollaufwand um Qualität sicherzustellen
\item Das gesamte Risiko der Budgetsicherheit liegt auf Kundenseite
\item Gesamtkosten sind für Auftraggeber theoretisch unbegrenzt
\vspace{-0.5cm}
\end{compactitem}
&
\setlength{\leftmargini}{0pt}
\begin{compactitem}
\setlength{\itemsep}{-1\parsep}
\MPT
\item Kunde legt gemeinsam mit Lieferant den Budgetrahmen und Riskshare fest
\item Qualität bleibt während des Projekts nachvollziehbar
\item Kunde kann Aufwände im Budgetrahmen steuern
\vspace{-0.5cm}
\end{compactitem}
\\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It is usually preferable to give us complete [minimal working examples (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer using `enumitem` instead of `paralist`; there's no need of `multirow` either. Notice how I set the vertical label; adjust the amount of lowering. Also `>{\centering}l` means nothing: use `c`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,tabularx,colortbl,graphicx}
\newenvironment{compactitem}
  {\begin{itemize}[nosep,leftmargin=*]}
  {\end{itemize}}

\makeatletter
% I'd prefer this
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
% Use the following if you really don't want any space above the lists
%\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\@minipagetrue\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent % just for the example
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|Y|Y|Y|}
\hline
\rowcolor[gray]{0.75}
  & \textbf{Herkömmlicher Festpreis} & \textbf{Time \& Material} &
    \textbf{Agiler Festpreis} \\ \hline\hline
\raisebox{-20ex}[0pt][0pt]{\rotatebox[origin=center]{90}{Kunde}} &
  - & -- & ++ \\
\cline{2-4}
&
\begin{compactitem}
\item Budgetsicherheit ist nicht gegeben, der Preis basiert nur auf Schätzwert um wieviel der ursprüngliche Festpreis überschritten wird
\item Risiko der Budgetsicherheit ist zwar geteilt, aber meist stärker auf Kundenseite
\end{compactitem}
&
\begin{compactitem}
\item Kunde kann die Aufwände im Detail im Budgetrahmen steuern
\item Hoher Kontrollaufwand um Qualität sicherzustellen
\item Das gesamte Risiko der Budgetsicherheit liegt auf Kundenseite
\item Gesamtkosten sind für Auftraggeber theoretisch unbegrenzt
\end{compactitem}
&
\begin{compactitem}
\item Kunde legt gemeinsam mit Lieferant den Budgetrahmen und Riskshare fest
\item Qualität bleibt während des Projekts nachvollziehbar
\item Kunde kann Aufwände im Budgetrahmen steuern
\end{compactitem}
\\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]